# Stable ±15 V symmetric power from USB

Tags: power-supply, usb

We would like to have a stable symmetric power supply with ±15 V.

At the moment we use two ICL 7660 to accomplish this (C=10 µF), with ±10 V for now:

[image: Similar to Positive Voltage Doubler circuit in ICL 7660 Datasheet]

The load consumes around 15 mA on + and - each, and through the ground go 30 mA. Without load the output voltage is 9.6 V but under load it drops asymmetrically to -6.5 V / + 7.2 V.

The idea is to power a DIY Scanning Tunnelling microscope. The measurements are performed high sampling rate so the ripple is visible.

It works okay, however there is this 10 kHz ripple, it would be great to get rid of it.

Also it seems that the voltage is unstable sometimes.

Is there a way to make this circuit more stable? I was thinking to use 2 passive low-pass filters (4.7 kΩ, 47 nF). One between +10V and GND, the other between -10V and GND.

Comment: You shouldn't try to draw 330mA from the 10V rail without over-current of the USB bus. USB has a maximum specified current draw of 500mA (and that is only if your device is smart enough to negotiate for it, otherwise you should not draw more than limited to 100mA). You are stepping up the voltage, which means input current goes up. 330mA @ 10V equates to 660mA @ 5V (probably higher current due to losses), so that is way out of spec for USB.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I see, thanks for the comment... So I guess it's best to only connect it only to a 1 A+ USB power supply.

Comment: I just updated the question, it's just 2x 15 mA and the motor gets powered separately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that this even works, even more surprised that you claim it works okay.

[Here](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/icl7/icl7660.pdf) is the datasheet for the ICL7660. Let's take a look:

[image]

Your 330 mA is way off the charts. The first trick to knowing that it's not usable for much is that they don't even *mention* the maximum current draw on the front page of the datasheet.

The reliable way to get a symmetric ±10 V with more than a couple of mA output is to use a switch mode converter. There are a few topologies to chose from, and a lot of simple ICs to use.

Now, to your oscillator question. The datasheet shows that you can *lower* the oscillation frequency by connecting a capacitor to the OSC pin:

[image]

Buried in the details is that you can also *increase* the frequency, by driving the OSC pin directly:

[image]

Increasing the frequency may very well give you a lower output ripple, at the cost of conversion efficiency. The datasheet also mentions that low ESR capacitors will help. I have a feeling that you're seeing excessive ripple because the device is simply not designed for these currents.

Comment: Hey sorry for the confusion, actually the motor gets power from another current source. In fact only 15 mA are used on each rail. I also updated the question.

Comment: @Philip I see. Still, 15 mA is a bit much for the 7660, as you can see when you measure the voltage drop.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use a commercially-available professionally-designed DC-DC converter, search Digi-Key as example.

http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/power-supplies-board-mount/dc-dc-converters/4325599?k=&pkeyword=&pv1525=44&pv1525=150&pv1526=22&pv1526=6&FV=15c0003%2Cfff40042%2Cfff800df%2C16fc0009%2C16fc000b%2C16fc000c%2C16fc0014%2C16fc008d&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

But check details of specifications carefully, not all of them are of high quality in terms of ripples.

This will save you a lot of time and money.